# Eclipse - ADT plugin not auto-completing

Tags: android, installation

I'm trying to build a hello-world program here to check my android kit installation. But the problem is that our good old auto importing functionality of eclipse using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> just isn't working. 
I believe there's been some goof up in installation from my end. Any insights on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[This link](http://blog.tremend.ro/2006/10/19/eclipse-java-autocompletion-not-working/#comment-17396) helped me.
Specifically I had to do:
Go Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced
Make sure “Other Java Proposals” is ticked (and all other Java stuff)

Comment: there is no option of “Other Java Proposals” in my eclipse :( I am stuck in same situation.

Comment: Just check for everything there. My problem was exactly here, I checked the options that were unchecked, and works like a charm :D

Comment: I clicked the "Java" options (all were unchecked) and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

@mindReader

Probably, in your computer, the ctrl + space has been occupied by the lanaguage switch option.
I am in this case. After I changed the ctrl+ space for changing language to shift+space.

I have the loving auto-completing back in ADT under ubuntu, hope it helps you~

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but anyways. This will auto complete your imports:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: Yes, that is there but that won't help with auto-completing..would it?

Comment: Yes. It will. If it doesn't make sure that the .jar file you need for that class is in your build path.

Comment: You only need to check your build jars/paths if you are adding an extra library. If it's core android, you should already have android.jar in your path. In most cases Ctrl+space+o (Organize imports) will work as stated by Caner.

Comment: Most of the core libraries are working fine. But for 'View', even  after importing 'View.OnClickListener' explicitly, it's not auto-completing 'View'

Comment: Thanks for your inputs guys. But the issue persists.