# autoComplete suggestion doesn't work in eclipse java

Tags: android, eclipse, autocomplete

I want to use autoComplete suggestions in eclipse (Android) but doesn't work.
For example when I type "Stri" it doesn't suggest "String" or for anything else it doesn't work!!
I've ticked Windows->Preferences->...->Content Assist-> Advanced but still doesn't work.
I've reinstall eclipse but still doesn't work!

I did what similar topics said but doesn't work!
like it

[Eclipse - ADT plugin not auto-completing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673663/eclipse-adt-plugin-not-auto-completing)

this screenshot from eclipse :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0fkz.png

Comment: while typing Press Ctrl+ enter it will Show Suggestion

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse - ADT plugin not auto-completing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673663/eclipse-adt-plugin-not-auto-completing)

Comment: Better switch to Android Studio. Not yet convinced read this http://androidbinder.blogspot.in/2015/06/getting-started-with-android-studio-m.html

Comment: kumar, you're right eclipse is going outdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer a big thanks to user1909533

Go to Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist and paste "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz." (note the dot after z) into the "Auto activation triggers for Java:" field. This worked for me ! Now as i type I get autocomplete options

Answer (score 0):

Check in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced to have this

- checked:

  - Java Non-Type Proposals
  - Java Proposals
  - SWT Template Proposals
  - Template Proposals

and this

- UNchecked:

  - API Tools Proposals
  - Basic Proposals
  - Java Type Proposals
  - Jax-WS Proposals
  - JASB Proposals
  - JPA Proposals
- Word Proposals
  This is in the "Default content assis list"

Answer (score 0):

By default in Eclipse you only have to press "Ctrl-space" for autocomplete.

If this doesn't work go to the Eclipse 
Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content assist -> Advanced

In this Advanced you have to checked

1. Java Non-Type Proposals
2. Java Proposals
3. SWT Template Proposals
4. Template Proposals